# who first captured UIControlEventTouchDown?

Tags: ios, controls

first UIApplication ,or Control ?

before  I think the first is  UIApplication.
but now I think maybe the first is  Control .

the Basis is below：

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIControl

sendAction:to:forEvent:
In response to a given event, forwards an action message to the application object for dispatching to a target.

this cause me to trust the UIControl first get the Control Event before application  .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The UIEvent class and the UIControlEvent constants are not the same thing. An event object encapsulates information about a touch sequence, a control event is a UIControl's interpretation of a particular touch sequence within its bounds.

The sequence is:

1. Operating system receives and delivers UIEvent object to UIApplication.
2. `[UIApplication sendEvent:]` delivers the event to the
   key window
3. `[UIWindow sendEvent:]` delivers the (touch) event to the
   hit tested view
4. `[UIView touches...]` event handling methods called

   The UIControl object interprets touches and determines the UIControlEvent constant if any
5. `[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:]` is called once or more times
6. `[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:]` is called
7. The action is performed on the target

So the UIEvent starts with UIApplication, but the UIControlEvent starts with the UIControl.

Comment: why not  directly pass Action to the target by UIControl 。 what is the meaning of “[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:]"